# java processbuilder readline cpu intensive

Tags: java, readline, processbuilder

Running an external C code from within JAVA using ProcessBuilder. The (compiled) C code takes ~1 sec to produce output - relatively slow.

What I am noticing is that the BufferedReader Readline seems to be pretty CPU intensive for until the C code completes. And since I have to run the external C code every 5 seconds, the CPU utilization adds up. Here is the readline code:

```
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = null;
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                this.pw.add(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I can post the entire code - however, it is very similar to what you see on [this page](http://thilosdevblog.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/proper-handling-of-the-processbuilder/).

[Here is the JProfiler screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQEuy.jpg)

Any advice?

Comment: I have a feeling it is occupying CPU time but it is not itself intensive... it's merely blocking for input.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. Looks like i can use "br.ready()" to check before readline. This does not stop blocking but reduces the block time by almost 50% in my case.